# Linregress giving incorrect result

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, linear-regression

I am a big fan of Stack Overflow and am sure my question will be answered here. I am using Scipy to do linear regression. But at a particular set of inputs I am not getting the correct output. (Python 2.5, SciPy 0.10.1 Windows 7 32 bit)

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
from numpy import arange
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,2]
y = arange(1,36)
s,i,r,p,st = linregress(x,y)
```

Here value of s comes as 9.241573, but Excel reports slope to be 0.026.

Am I missing something? Help.

Comment: Does it help if you make x to an numpy array? `x=numpy.array([0,0,...])` Don't forget to import numpy :)

Comment: @halex - I've tried that, but no - it doesn't. linregress treates both numpy arrays and pythonic arrays equally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have the arguments the wrong way around:

```
s,i,r,p,st = linregress(y,x)
```

gives `s = 0.026330532212885151`. Excel and Scipy have the arguments in the opposite order.

Comment: That is interesting. Excel says `SLOPE(y,x)` and scipy says `linregress(x,y)`... However, `SLOPE(y,x)=linregress(y,x)`.

Comment: The variable names of `x` and `y` in the question are also swapped